# How updating existing project from remote repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I have my project on bitbucket using Git. I want to work on this project from several computers. Commiting the project using EGit in Eclipse works without problems.

So far I always delete my project and import a fresh project from the latest commit from bitbucket.

But how can I update an existing project in eclipse based on the state of the remote bitbucket repository? Without having to delete it?

When I try to pull I get:

> The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration

Comment: Just `pull`? Whats the concrete problem? (Remember to `push` after comitting)

Comment: Trying "pull" gives: `The current branch is not configured for pull
No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration`. I also tried `Remote > Fetch From...` but there it says `everything up to date`. Which is strange because I can see the recent commit from another pc in my bitbucket repo in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. The following entry must be placed under .git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true

    [branch "master"] 
        remote = origin 
        merge = refs/heads/master 
    [remote "origin"] 
        url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/project.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You do a pull request, or Team / Pull if you are using eGit.